# Data on shop/restaurant discounts (preferably UK)

Tags: data-request, uk, shopping, restaurant

Apps like Groupon, VoucherCodes show shop and restaurant offers/discounts near you.

Are there any open data sets containing discount information over a large period of time? I am looking preferably in the UK.